# QGIS layers don't overlay after trying 'enable on the fly' and CRS settings

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I know there are already many questions about this topic, but none of the answers helped me so far. I have two layers I want to overlay in QGIS. One of them is an Excell file with the coordinates of households in it. I changed it to .csv and projected it in QGIS with 'add deliminate text layer'. The other one are the outlines of the provinces of Dhulikhel municipality, Nepal. I got these from my colleague. I want to project the households in the provinces.

I would like to project these layers in WGS84 UTM zone 45N EPSG 32645. 
The first layer is in this projection, the second one isn't, it is in a for me unknown 'Generated CRS'. I tried enable on the fly projection and than the save as option for the second layer. This however did not work. It seems to be something with the spatial reference system units.

I hope someone can help me. These are the properties of my layers:

Households:

```
General:
Storage type of this layer: Delimited text file
Source for this layer: file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Administrator/Desktop/GIS/Household_survey_results%20(6).csv?delimiter=,&delimiterType=plain&xField=Longitude&yField=Latitude
Geometry type of the features in this layer: Point
The number of features in this layer: 1681
Editing capabilities of this layer: 
Extents:
In layer spatial reference system units : xMin,yMin 85.5281,27.6066 : xMax,yMax 85.5771,27.6372
Layer Spatial Reference System:
+proj=utm +zone=45 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
```

Provinces:

```
General:
Storage type of this layer: PGeo
Source for this layer: C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/GIS/Dhulikhel_Digital_Data/Administrative.mdb|layername=Ward_line
Geometry type of the features in this layer: Line
The number of features in this layer: 34
Editing capabilities of this layer: Fast Access to Features at ID
Extents:
In layer spatial reference system units : xMin,yMin 353921.13,3054982.59 : xMax,yMax 360199.97,3058637.05
Layer Spatial Reference System:
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=87 +k=0.9999 +x_0=500000 +y_0=0 +a=6377299.36559538 +b=6356098.359005156 +units=m +no_defs
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the extent given, the first layer is pretty sure in degrees.

So try EPSG:4326 for this one.

The second one looks OK at first sight, but it is rather Kalianpur 1880 mixed with UTM 45N.
This is nearly, but not exact Kalianpur 1975 UTM 45 as used in India.

If you discover offsets of about 200m for all data, you have to apply +towgs84 parameters.

Comment: Thanks! I changed it and now it works perfect! I didn't know that you always had to use EPSG 4326 for degrees. Won't forget it anymore now!